# How do I efficiently delete all rows in a many-to-many relationship table that have a given destination exclusively on one side of the relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, query-optimization, relationship

I have a MySQL database with a relationship table which can be simplified to:

```
CREATE TABLE `Paths` (
  `origin` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `destination` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
)
```

This is a many-to-many relationship.
I want to delete all paths where all paths from that origin only lead to a certain place, e.g. `Neverland`.

This SQL should work:

```
DELETE FROM Paths WHERE origin IN (SELECT DISTINCT origin FROM Paths WHERE destination = 'Neverland') AND origin NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT origin FROM Paths WHERE destination <> 'Neverland');
```

But, is there a better, more efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want origin and destination to be NULLable?

Comment: @le dorifer - No, I suppose in this example you wouldn't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  Delete Paths
  From Paths p
  Where Not Exists  
      (Select * From paths 
       Where Origin = p.origin
       And Destination <> 'Neverland')
```

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect it to be any faster.. The relative speed of any two logical equivilent queries is more dependant on the table design and indices in place than on the particular syntax of the queries.   The major advantedge of this representation is that it reads more closely to the logical intent of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it's at least close.

```
DELETE Paths
FROM Paths
JOIN Paths AS pd
    ON Paths.origin = pd.destination
WHERE Paths.origin = 'Neverland'
```

This is the second syntax on 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Are you sure it's `po.origin = po.destination`? It seems like in a join both tables should be in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is improved:

```
DELETE FROM Paths WHERE destination= 'Neverland' AND origin NOT IN (SELECT origin FROM Paths WHERE branchto != 'Neverland');
```

But I still think it can be done better.